# JQuery can't hide images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've wrapped some images in a class called gallery. Then I tried to hide this class on document ready, but it's not working. What have I done wrong?

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Galleria Jquery</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        <!-- Inserire in questa sezione il codice javascript -->

        $("img").wrapAll("<div class='gallery'></div>");
        $(document).ready(function(){
                          $(".gallery").hide();
                          });

    </script>

    <style>
        <!-- Inserire in questa sezione le definizione di stile -->

    </style>



</head>

<body>

    <img src="img1.jpg" />
    <img src="img2.jpg" />
    <img src="img3.jpg" />
    <img src="img4.jpg" />

    <button id="prevbutton">Prev</button>
    <button id="nextbutton">Next</button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the js code inside `document.ready`

This is because when the js code is executed the `img`tag is not present in DOM

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // your code
})
```

alternatively you can put the js code near closing `body` tag

```
<body>
  // Html code
<script>
  /js code
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Galleria Jquery</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>


    <style>
        <!-- Inserire in questa sezione le definizione di stile -->

    </style>



</head>

<body>

    <img src="img1.jpg" />
    <img src="img2.jpg" />
    <img src="img3.jpg" />
    <img src="img4.jpg" />

    <button id="prevbutton">Prev</button>
    <button id="nextbutton">Next</button>
    <script>
        <!-- Inserire in questa sezione il codice javascript -->
        $("img").wrapAll("<div class='gallery'></div>");
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".gallery").hide();
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").wrapAll("<div class='gallery'></div>");
  $(".gallery").hide();
});
```

Since `wrapAll` is synchronous the `hide` will only be called after the new wrappers are added to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask one more question please? I can't get the first child of my div "gallery". I've tried   $(".gallery img:first-child").show()

Comment: The above code selects the first div from the array of divs with the class `.gallery` and selects the `img` in it and calls the `show()` on it, I'm assuming thats what you require.